# Failed to list versions for org.roboguice:roboblender

Tags: android, gradle, guice, roboguice

I try to [install](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki/InstallationGradle) roboGuice on my android gradle project

```
project.dependencies {
    compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:3.+'
    provided 'org.roboguice:roboblender:3.+'
}
```

I get this error:

```
12:43:53 AM: Executing external task 'buildDependents'...
WARNING [Project: :app] WARNING: runProguard is deprecated (and will soon stop working); change to "minifyEnabled" instead

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not resolve org.roboguice:roboguice:3.+.
     Required by:
         StopCall:app:unspecified
      > Failed to list versions for org.roboguice:roboguice.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/roboguice/roboguice/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/roboguice/roboguice/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > cache.corp.google.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
      > Failed to list versions for org.roboguice:roboguice.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/roboguice/roboguice/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/roboguice/roboguice/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > cache.corp.google.com
   > Could not resolve org.roboguice:roboblender:3.+.
     Required by:
         StopCall:app:unspecified
      > Failed to list versions for org.roboguice:roboblender.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/roboguice/roboblender/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/roboguice/roboblender/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > cache.corp.google.com
      > Failed to list versions for org.roboguice:roboblender.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/roboguice/roboblender/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/roboguice/roboblender/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > cache.corp.google.com

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.459 secs
cache.corp.google.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
12:43:54 AM: External task execution finished 'buildDependents'.
```

Then

searching in maven [repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.roboguice/roboguice/3.0.1) I used this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    complie 'org.roboguice:roboguice:3.0.1'
}
```

and then I got this error:

```
12:52:50 AM: Executing external task 'build'...
WARNING [Project: :app] WARNING: runProguard is deprecated (and will soon stop working); change to "minifyEnabled" instead

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/eladb/MyWorkspace2/StopCall/app/build.gradle' line: 42

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method complie() for arguments [org.roboguice:roboguice:3.0.1] on project ':app'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.365 secs
Could not find method complie() for arguments [org.roboguice:roboguice:3.0.1] on project ':app'.
12:52:50 AM: External task execution finished 'build'.
```

and now I get:

[image]

what is the difference between `dependencies` and `project.dependencies` ?

why do we use `provided` ?

how can I fix each of the two above sections?

my build file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.2'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.stopcall.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    complie 'org.roboguice:roboguice:3.0.1'
}

//project.dependencies {
//    compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:3.+'
//    provided 'org.roboguice:roboblender:3.+'
//}
```